# how to prevent cancelled form submitting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter,

I have email function to send email,

Once I send request to send email and If cancel request before the email sent, And If refresh or if click on any button the previous action is executing(email is going out which is cancelled),

How can I prevent cancelled form submitting

Thanks

```
//form

<form id="finance_form" action="<?php echo site_url('invoice/updateFinaceStatus') ?>" method="post">
<select name="status">
    <option value="1">test</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit_status" value="1">Update</button>
</form>

 Controller

 public function updateFinaceStatus()
 {
    if ($this->input->post('submit_status')) {
        //sending email logic goes here
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please show some codes

Comment: Hi @MohitBumb I have added

Comment: You might want to take a look into generating session keys for the forms. After submit the key is used so it cannot be reinitiated and the form submit action will get an error.

Comment: Hi @Martin, thanks for the suggestion,

Comment: I believe I'm miundertanding your question or you're failing to comprehend how requests work. Once you submit a form and it begins being processed server-side, whatever you do on the client (browser) side is irrelevant for the server-side processing. If the form was correctly submitted, your controller takes over and you cannot stop it from reaching the mail sending routine from the browser.